# The logarithmic integral $\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log t}$ and Stirling numbers of the first kind

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, definite-integrals, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

From the **generating function** for the function $x/\log(1+x)$, denoting $(A_n)_{n\geq 0}$ the corresponding sequence of coefficients, by integration of the function $1/\log(t+1)$ over $ \left( 1,x-1 \right) $, after the change of variable, $u=t+1$ ($u$ is relabeled after as $t$ one more time) one has
$$\text{Li}(x)=\int_1^{x-1}\frac{1}{t}A_0dt+\int_1^{x-1}\frac{1}{t} \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{A_n}{n!}t^n\right)dt= $$
where I take the definition $\text{Li}(x):=\int_2^x \frac{dt}{\log t}$. Then I can use (if there are no mistakes) that $A_0:=f^{(0)}(0)\equiv f(0)=\frac{0}{\log 1}=\frac{0}{0}$, and **L'Hôpital's rule** assures me that this $A_0$ is $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\log(1+x)}=\lim_{x\to 0} 1+x=1$. By a change of the index of summation, 
$$=1\cdot\log(x-1)+\int_1^{x-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{A_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}t^n\cdot(-1)^n\cdot(-1)^n dt.$$

Then using the second identity deduced in [PROBLEMA 53 La Gaceta de la RSME Volumen 10, Número 1](http://gaceta.rsme.es/abrir.php?id=609), in Spanish (page 155), we can obatin the logarithmic integral written in terms of **Bernoulli numbers, binomial numbers, and Stirling numbers of the first kind** (those defined by brackets)

$$\text{Li}(x)=\log(x-1)-\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k\left((x-1)^{n+1}-1\right)}{(n+1)!}\begin{bmatrix}
        n\\
        k  
\end{bmatrix}\frac{B_{k+1}}{k+1}.$$

Also I know how to expand and simplify $(x-1)^{n+1}-1$ using **Newton's binomial theorem**, but I believe that today I was sufficiently artificious, and I believe that it isn't possible to get the sum of  the sums in the previous identity.

> **Question.** Was there any mistake in my computations? If yes, please say where and **provide your own final formula**. If my computations were right, take this as a proof verification and tell me if there are some inaccuracies or additional justifications that you want to notify to me. **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Many thanks @giobrach

Comment: All users **it is neccesary to say that** $x>2$.